# HTTPWebResponse Response string is truncated

Tags: c#, http

App is talking to a REST service.
Fiddler shows full good XML response coming in as the Apps response
The App is in French Polynesia and an identical copy in NZ works so the prime suspect seemed encoding but we have checked that out and came up empty handed.

Looking at the output string (UTF8 encoding) from the stream reader  you can see where it has been truncated. It is in an innocuous piece of xml. The downstream  error on an XmlDocument object claims to have an encountered an unexpected end of file while loading the string into an XML Document object which is fair enough.

The truncation point is
ns6:sts-krn>1&

which is part of 
ns6:sts-krn>1</ns6:sts-krn><

Is there any size limitation on the response string or some other parameter that we should check.
I am all out of ideas. Code Supplied as requested.

```
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
if (streamResponse != null)
{
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(streamResponse, encode);
    while (readStream.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        sb.Append((char)readStream.Read());
    }
    streamResponse.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please replace "thank you notes"/signature with sample of your code. Likely you reading it wrong/use wrong encoding. Also while editing post make sure to format sample data as code too.

Comment: Look at actual bytes in Fiddler - I bet encoding is not Utf8 and "which is part of `ns6:sts-krn>1</n`" is not true (there is likely more text after `1` that you don't see in text editor).

Comment: The same REST engine and the same app is installed in NZ. i.e. it is a closed system. In NZ the same test transaction produces the same string and it is not truncated by the code. The encoding is definitely utf-8 from the response header -> xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes". Fiddler in FP is able to view the response in XML mode without a problem. our man in FP went into the fiddler response at hex level and confirmed there were no bogus characters in the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using `using` blocks:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (streamResponse != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(streamResponse, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sb.Append(readStream.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This will ensure that your `WebResponse`, `Stream`, and `StreamReader` all get cleaned up, regardless of whether there are any exceptions.

---

The reasoning that led me to think about `using` blocks was:

1. Some operation was not completed
2. There were no try/catch blocks hiding exceptions, so if the operation wasn't completed due to exceptions, we would know about it.
3. There were objects which implement `IDisposable` which were not in `using` blocks

Conclusion: try implementing the `using` blocks to see if disposing the objects will cause the operation to complete.

I added this because the reasoning is actually quite general. The same reasoning works for "my mail message doesn't get sent for two minutes". In that case, the operation which isn't completed is "send email" and the instances are the `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` objects.

Comment: So elegant compared to my code. Won't know if it has made a difference until FP are available tomorrow.

Comment: Why did this fix the issue (which was partial responses, not a hang or no response at all)?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this would be:

```
string responseString;
using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(streamResponse, encode))
{
    responseString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

For debugging, I would suggest writing that response stream to a file so that you can see exactly what was read. In addition, you might consider using a single byte encoding (like ISO-8859-1) to read the data and write to the file.

You should check the `response.ContentType` property to see if some other text encoding is used.

Comment: Have Added response.ContentType it returns 'text/plain'