# Reading http page with error http 500 error: incomplete result

Tags: c#

I try to read a web page that always throws a http 500 internal server error. When accessing it with firefox or internet explorer I got the full page (~200KB). When I read it with my program, I only got a part of the page (~64KB). This is my code:

```
try
{
     HttpWebRequest request = null;
     request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:// ... ");
     request.Timeout = 30000;
     request.Method = "GET";

     responseContent = null;
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
     responseContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
     Stream responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
     responseContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

When I check the traffic with fiddler, I see that Http 500 is returned when accessing the page with the browser and with my program. **But** in all three cases I see the **full page** in fiddler.

What can I do, to get the full page? The web page I'm try to read is not under my control.

The solutions in "HTTPWebResponse Response string is truncated" do not change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPWebResponse Response string is truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196324/httpwebresponse-response-string-is-truncated)

Comment: Have you compared results using an IE browser to see differences.  Normally issues are with the http headers not set correctly.  When and http connection is made there is a negotiation that take place between client and server using the headers.  If the headers aren't compatible then errors will occur.  You probably need to add/modify current headers to work with server.

Comment: the 64KB that the application got, is that actually consist of the start of the full-page, or the end?

Comment: The http 500 error is thrown with my program **as well** as with the browser. Making the headers identical to the one with IE doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Thariq Nugrohotomo: It's the start of the full page.